# Loading Javascript for a Modal inserted at runtime

Tags: javascript

How do i execute this javascript only after the html is loaded.

```
<input type="text" id="rmb" name="price" class="price span1" value="2" />
<input type="text" id="sgd" />


    $('#rmb').keyup(function(){
        $('#sgd').val(Number(this.value/4.7).toFixed(2));
    });
```

inside my .js file , used to detect for submit button clicked

```
dialogEditItem.one('click', '.submit', function(e){
```

my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZLr9N/

my modal html

```
<script id="product-data" type="text/html">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3><%= data.name %></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        <input type="text" id="rmb" name="price" class="price span1" value="<%= data.price %>">
                        <input type="text" id="sgd" />
                    ...
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn green submit">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn red cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: How do you "load" the modal?

Comment: dialogEditItem.one('click', '.submit', function(e){

Comment: Then just put your snippet inside that handler?

Comment: @m90 i tried that, it didnt work :(

Comment: My guess would be that you bind `$('#rmb')` before it is present in the DOM. You coud try `$(document).on('keyup', '#rmb', handler)` instead.

Comment: @m90 you should put your comment as answer. Fixed. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to bind a handler to your input element before it is part of the DOM:

```
$('#rmb').keyup(handlerFn); // when #rmb is not present yet the jQuery object will be empty and no handler will be bound
```

Instead use event delegation, binding the handler to the `document` object that is always present:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#rmb', handlerFn); //document will always be present, no matter if #rmb is added to the DOM lateron, so binding will be successful
```

See **[the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)** on `.on()` and delegation.